# Many Send-Q have packets TCP connections, is this abnormality? what caused this?

Tags: centos, tcp, netstat

The `125.193.242.25` is a CDN node, and when I analyze the TCP connect, there shows below information:

```
[root@hkk10 ~]# netstat -na
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3311                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.26:80           118.25.234.139:54812        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           123.151.77.74:65233         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           123.151.77.74:46127         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           125.39.132.70:56691         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           125.39.46.58:62253          SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           123.151.77.74:52071         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           123.151.77.74:42819         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           123.151.77.74:58816         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           117.136.123.136:51361       SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           113.96.219.243:32847        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           113.100.245.181:60962       SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           123.151.77.74:63496         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           123.151.77.74:65492         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3319              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.198:16044        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.181:44214        SYN_RECV    
....            
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.91.95:25672         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.69:19422         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          14.215.176.21:39372         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.90.12:23081         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.11.18:19140         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.12.101:3860         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.45.66:57152         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.165:21806        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.49:24690         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          14.215.176.21:39373         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.49:24688         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.44:10806         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.227:10877        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.49:24689         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          175.153.170.6:19427         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.6.48:7489           SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.161:54779        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.1.149:32928         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.6.48:7487           SYN_RECV    
    ....
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.79.139:58193        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.227:10876        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          14.215.176.148:44144        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          124.127.202.190:61350       SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.49:24685         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.6.48:7488           SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.64.131:42079        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.64.35:46918         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          175.153.170.6:19426         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.227:10879        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.91.95:25388         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.161:54784        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.227:10878        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          1.202.183.178:61356         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.11.18:19146         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.12.101:3859         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.44:10805         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.64.131:42083        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.181:44215        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.69:19421         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          111.225.149.36:10412        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          112.91.129.16:61731         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          1.202.88.54:61363           SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.161:54783        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.165:21807        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.65.44:10809         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.69:19417         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.198:16045        SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.69:19416         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.49:24686         SYN_RECV    
tcp        0   3222 125.193.242.25:443          211.91.251.54:64858         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:37024        182.16.53.42:80             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0    574 125.193.242.25:443          218.92.146.22:55143         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           180.76.196.112:27094        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.29:80           47.92.251.118:34366         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.161:80           212.64.52.114:37716         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          27.26.128.18:61980          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          14.116.141.124:58850        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.27:80           47.92.251.118:56254         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          183.148.229.155:50025       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.27:80           207.148.4.159:40978         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          125.126.178.149:60483       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          125.126.176.135:55443       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.162:22           222.186.42.15:45526         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.163:80           106.12.128.249:55510        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  18346 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.98.145:49839        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.27:80           180.76.196.112:43346        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:37040        182.16.53.42:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.152.17.126:49965        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           115.159.200.27:37428        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   1774 125.193.242.25:443          183.237.61.33:56387         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          14.215.176.15:60893         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   1774 125.193.242.25:443          112.47.27.129:52761         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.1.250:64177         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.163:22           222.186.42.15:14784         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0  11872 125.193.242.25:22           110.184.220.42:36356        ESTABLISHED 
....      
tcp        0      0 103.200.32.189:80           106.12.128.249:49236        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          46.229.168.161:19440        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           111.30.142.78:63381         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.72.47.181:65054         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          183.148.229.155:50001       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.1.250:64190         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          125.126.178.149:60494       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          46.229.168.149:42566        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.162:80           106.12.128.249:59208        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.26:80           180.76.196.213:26994        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   1774 125.193.242.25:443          122.228.230.81:52112        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          110.249.202.80:63522        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          59.54.204.125:37715         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          125.126.176.135:55485       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.91.136:57312        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           183.237.61.32:62939         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          218.67.19.234:43372         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.164:80           106.13.6.247:44332          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.64.244:53446        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.26:80           115.159.206.130:41058       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          46.229.168.136:11308        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   3520 125.193.242.25:443          223.95.183.152:50486        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0   1615 125.193.242.25:443          36.105.156.55:64978         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.28:80           45.32.198.211:32882         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.1.226:64156         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.165:80           95.179.196.83:43996         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:37034        182.16.53.42:80             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          110.249.201.243:60265       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   3222 125.193.242.25:443          112.132.154.143:50367       LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      1 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.98.145:49829        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          110.249.201.48:50443        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        1     32 125.193.242.25:443          219.133.46.86:49364         CLOSING     
tcp        0   4498 125.193.242.25:443          183.148.229.155:49989       LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.164:80           180.76.196.213:33820        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.26:443          117.183.234.104:54278       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   1890 103.200.32.189:443          223.96.79.87:58711          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:42208        154.222.136.152:80          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.26:80           111.231.92.94:38480         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  21685 125.193.242.25:443          125.126.176.135:55435       LAST_ACK    
tcp        1     32 125.193.242.25:443          219.133.46.52:60816         CLOSING     
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          113.100.245.181:60398       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          157.255.192.119:53831       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0    259 125.193.242.25:443          36.159.127.146:52696        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          106.17.1.88:54835           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           120.87.127.125:61177        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.98.145:49801        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      1 125.193.242.25:443          171.108.233.172:63003       LAST_ACK    
tcp        0    574 125.193.242.25:443          183.237.146.16:50081        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.29:80           106.12.128.249:39778        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  31857 125.193.242.25:443          116.11.88.113:22111         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          121.32.181.69:61554         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.181.180.255:60736       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        1     32 125.193.242.25:443          14.116.141.124:58826        CLOSING     
tcp        0   3210 103.200.32.189:443          218.92.146.22:53004         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          36.105.156.55:65018         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:37020        182.16.53.42:80             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           132.232.138.233:58279       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  19760 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.98.145:49838        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          183.148.229.155:49991       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          46.229.168.146:58580        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          14.116.141.124:58833        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        1     32 125.193.242.25:443          14.116.141.124:58874        CLOSING     
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.29:80           95.179.196.83:40760         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.163:80           207.148.4.159:40032         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           106.12.128.249:49248        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          183.39.54.85:58522          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          36.105.156.55:65009         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0    574 103.200.32.189:443          220.194.216.34:61884        FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           111.30.142.252:63213        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:80           118.126.98.25:55889         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          58.63.99.47:53508           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.72.71.102:62361         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  21515 125.193.242.25:443          36.105.156.55:64992         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          120.231.144.185:60946       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        1     32 125.193.242.25:443          219.133.46.48:54554         CLOSING     
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          171.108.148.221:60383       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   1805 125.193.242.25:443          46.229.168.149:23778        FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0   2112 103.193.242.26:443          202.104.220.107:57949       LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.161:22           222.186.42.163:13216        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          112.97.49.46:57784          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          183.166.137.210:46073       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:37036        182.16.53.42:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.26:80           118.126.98.25:65450         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.28:80           106.13.6.247:39608          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.27:80           95.179.196.83:55736         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          112.97.55.50:50886          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.26:80           106.13.6.247:60720          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:37038        182.16.53.42:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          58.63.99.47:53546           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0    874 125.193.242.25:443          58.208.138.151:54061        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 103.200.32.188:443          117.183.12.158:49921        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          183.148.229.155:50035       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.45.80:49793         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          171.110.14.63:62844         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          183.148.229.155:50019       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   3560 125.193.242.25:443          36.159.127.146:52730        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          125.126.176.135:55451       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          223.104.63.49:52221         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          120.87.127.125:62151        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0  18990 125.193.242.25:443          223.72.47.181:65064         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   1750 103.200.32.187:443          124.239.182.169:60647       LAST_ACK    
....        
tcp        0   2112 125.193.242.25:443          119.36.209.52:59196         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0  24782 125.193.242.25:443          223.72.71.102:62364         ESTABLISHED 
...          
tcp        0      0 43.246.212.162:80           47.92.251.118:56966         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          113.220.34.51:55458         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0  10090 125.193.242.25:443          36.105.156.55:65007         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0    574 125.193.242.25:443          114.112.160.36:52394        LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          36.159.127.145:59825        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          112.97.240.252:49714        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0    574 103.200.32.188:443          220.194.216.34:51137        FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.26:80           212.64.52.114:44344         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        1     32 125.193.242.25:443          113.100.245.181:60360       CLOSING     
...
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.28:80           180.76.196.213:37246        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          117.181.249.48:63118        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0    160 125.193.242.25:443          117.136.40.154:40454        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 103.193.242.28:80           212.64.52.114:46798         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          14.28.39.88:56845           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 125.193.242.25:443          36.105.156.55:65015         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   3222 125.193.242.25:443          117.187.46.21:56430         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 :::3311                     :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     788359 /vhs/kangle/kangle.manage
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     788361 /vhs/kangle/kangle.manage
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     788363 /vhs/kangle/kangle.manage
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     788365 /vhs/kangle/kangle.manage
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     788367 /vhs/kangle/kangle.manage
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     788369 /vhs/kangle/kangle.manage
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     788371 /vhs/kangle/kangle.manage
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12871  public/cleanup
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12878  private/tlsmgr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12882  private/rewrite
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12886  private/bounce
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12890  private/defer
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12894  private/trace
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12898  private/verify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12902  public/flush
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12906  private/proxymap
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12910  private/proxywrite
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12914  private/smtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12918  private/relay
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12922  public/showq
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9353   @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12926  private/error
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12930  private/retry
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12934  private/discard
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12938  private/local
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12942  private/virtual
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12946  private/lmtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12950  private/anvil
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12954  private/scache
unix  12     [ ]         DGRAM                    12433  /dev/log
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    10235  @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     788373 /vhs/kangle/kangle.manage
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9194897 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9194890 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9194889 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9194866 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9194859 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9194858 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9154579 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9131277 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8064393 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    165319 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    19506  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    12997  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    12961  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12957  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12956  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12953  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12952  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12949  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12948  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12945  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12944  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12941  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12940  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12937  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12936  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12933  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12932  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12929  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12928  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12925  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12924  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12921  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12920  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12917  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12916  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12913  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12912  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12909  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12908  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12905  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12904  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12901  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12900  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12897  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12896  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12893  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12892  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12889  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12888  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12885  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12884  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12881  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12880  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12877  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12876  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12874  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12873  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12870  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12869  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12867  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12866  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    12819  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12393  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12392  
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    10254  
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    10253
```

---

there I have some questions:

1. you see there have many State `SYN_RECV`, is this normal?
2. you see there have many Send-Q have packets TCP connections, is this abnormality? why caused this?

Answer (score 0):

SYN_RECV:
If they stay like that for long then whatever listens on :443 is not accept()ing connections any more. I.e. the server doesn't do accept() on the incoming connections. If that's a web server then that can be normal because it has maxed out the number of connections it is willing to serve in parallel and leaves the rest waiting.

Send-Q:
This means that the server has written data to the socket by those have either not been transmitted yet or have not been acked by the remote end, so the kernel has to remember them.

This is normal in most cases when a connection is transferring data and your numbers look small enough. Since this is a CDN node, it can also be caused by clients gone missing (e.g. losing network connectivity) where the server hasn't figured that out and the kernel is waiting for the TCP ACKs to come back.

You can potentially enable tcp keepalives and reduce the server's timeouts to alleviate the problem.